# Multicollinearity Check in statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

What does that mean by "a linear dependence exists among three or even more variables" in multicollinearity?

Can somebody explain it in plain English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what they say : the variables are not independent since some of them are just linear combinations of other.

May I suggest you have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity ?

Comment: I've read the wikipedia but I can just read it through, but still I am having a hard time to understand the picture.

Comment: Just suppose that you have a model such as $Z=a + b X +c Y$ and that, for any point you have $Y = d + e X$. So you have a collinearity between $Y$ and $X$ and then $Z$ is just a linear function of $X$. Is this clearer ?

Comment: I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: Suppose a matrix in which one column is twice another column. Does this make a problem ? It is very similar to collinearity.

Comment: People say collinearity makes a problem for a regression analysis. Can I get some explanation..

Comment: This is exactly what I was meaning in my first comment. Consider now the matrix built for a linear least square regression and suppose that the matrix is such as in my second comment. This is why, good regression tools start searching if collinearities or almost collinerities exist among the supposed independent variables.

Comment: Look at http://dss.wikidot.com/multicollinearity-and-singularity

Comment: I have just visited the website you gave me and I have one paragraph, which is kind of abstract to me. Can I get an explanation of it from you. "Statistically, you do not want singularity or multicollinearity because calculation of the regression coefficients is done through matrix inversion. Consequently, if singularity exists, the inversion is impossible, and if multicollinearity exists the inversion is unstable"